# rewrite rule not redirecting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect one (htm) file to a php file.

my rewrite rule looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^market-intelligence/rfp/rfp-awards/proposals/winning-proposals_subscribers\.htm$ market-intelligence/rfp/rfp-awards/proposals/index.php [L,R=301]
```

But it's not redirecting. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: What URL are you trying to test it? What is filesystem path of this .htaccess file? Are there more rules too?

Comment: Yes, there were more rules. And that question clued me into the problem. I was proclaiming a more general rule prior to this one, which was overwriting it.

Comment: Yes order of rules is very important.

Comment: If you want to put something about the code being right, but to check the order of rules, I'll go ahead and give you a big checkmark! Thanks!

Comment: sure I posted my answer below explaining this ordering business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order of rules is of utmost important in .htaccess. In general one should keep all external redirect rules before internal rewrite rules. As it might happen than internal rewrite rules can change the `REQUEST_URI` variable and that can make `R=301` rules either fail or misfire.

For ex if your above rule appears below a front controller kind of rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^foo$ /bar [L,R=301]
```

It will **not redirect /foo to /bar**.